# mkdir && cd windows alias

Tags: windows, cmd, doskey

I am trying to make a directory and immediately change into it with a DOSKEY. I thought this would work but it gives me the error `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`

```
DOSKEY md=mkdir $* && cd $*
```

Does anyone know why this is wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Why do you need DOSKEY to do this. `mkdir yyy & cd yyy` The $* represents -all- command line variables. Are you sure that is what you want? Quoting is needed if the new directory can have a space character. `MKDIR "%*" & CD "%*"`

Comment: @Liturgist I'm trying to create an alias which is why I am using doskey and the reason I had `$*` was because I was getting my information from a bad source. Good call on the quotes but that command doesn't work. using `"$*"` works in place of `"%*"` though. % isn't recognized by doskey

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding the answer [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490894.aspx)

```
DOSKEY md=mkdir "$1"$tcd "$1"
```

I was trying to use `&&` instead of `$t`

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
C:>doskey aaa=MKDIR "$*"$tCD "$*"

C:>doskey /macros
aaa=MKDIR "$*"$tCD "$*"

C:>aaa arf

C:>
13:33:59.15  C:\Users\pwatson\x\arf
C:>
```